# Is there any way to open files by 'number' in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

Let's say I've got a directory with 10 files, each of them named badgeX, X being a number, and I want to open badge3, how can I open it without writing badge3 and tab for .txt? Is there any way to open it by its "number" on a list, for example let's say badge3 is archive 3 in the directory, so I do 'xdg-open badge3.txt' and it'd run. Thank you.

Comment: With zsh, you could do this: type `3`, press tab and have it complete to `badge3.txt`. Is switching shells an option?

Comment: `xdgopen *3.txt` may do the trick if there is only a `badge3.txt`, and not also a `otherfile3.txt` for example. Alternatively, consider using `fzf`. You type `3.` and it only displays files containing that in their name.